# IONIC 4 Setting Max value that can be inputted

Tags: input, ionic4, angular2-template

I want to limit the user input in ion-input to just 1000, not the max length of the user input.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: You should add a validator to your input field for such an action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumble on the same problem with me, I found the solution by using 'max' Validators. You can about all available Validators here:

[Angular Validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators)

Answer (score 0):

You set this "maxlength" property

like, This

```
<ion-input type="text" maxlength="1000"></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a size prop

```
<ion-input type="text" size="1000"></ion-input>
```